# validate form for dynamically created inputs count

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am dynamically creating the inputs in the form

I want user to enter at least 'n' elements.

```
<html lang="en-US">

    <head>
    <meta name="referrer" content="origin">
    <script>
        var counter = 0;
        var limit = 50;

        function addInput(divName, arrName){
             if (counter == limit)  {
                  alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
             }
             else {
                  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
              var af = "autofocus"
                  newdiv.innerHTML = "<input id='my-div-"+counter+"' type='text' name='" + arrName + "[]' required autofocus=" + af + ">";
                  document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
                  document.getElementById('my-div-'+counter).focus();
                  counter++;
             }
        }

    function validateForm(){
        var frm = document.forms['simples'];
        a = parseInt(frm.elements['myInputs_1[]'].length)
        var sum = parseInt(frm.elements['myInputs_1[]'].length)
        if(parseInt(sum) < 4){
            alert("You must write at least 4 sentences ");
            return false;
        }
    }

    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
            <form name="simples" action="part.php" align="center" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="POST">
                        <div id = "dynamicInputHolder_1">
                         <b>Emotion </b><input type="text" value="" name="emotion" id="emotion" class="generatedEmotion" readonly>
                         <input type="hidden" value="" name="uniqueID" id="uniqueID">
                         <div id="dynamicInput_1">
                                <textarea rows="5" cols="50" readonly class="floating-box">
    John arrived at Sally's house to pick her up. John and Sally were going to a fancy restaurant that evening for a dinner. John was little nervous because he was going to ask Sally to marry him.</textarea>
                         </div>
                         <input type="button" value="Add connecting sentences" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput_1', 'myInputs_1');">
                         </div>

                     <br>
                <input type="submit" value="show me what is next">
                </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

The method `validateForm()` works only if number text boxes are greater than equal to 2, for 0 and 1 it does not work.

Please not that this is minimal example, in real website, I have many such `div`s collecting input in multiple arrays, so I am summing them over something like:

`var sum = parseInt(frm.elements['myInputs_1[]'].length) + parseInt(frm.elements['myInputs_2[]'].length) + parseInt(frm.elements['myInputs_3[]'].length)`

but it may happen that few of the arrays are empty.

How do I check that collectively there are atleast `n` inputs?

Comment: @clabe45, `myInputs_1[]` is NOT a div, it is a name given to the input type element and because of `[``]` it is an `html` array. What do you mean by how can you take? It is in the code. I referred the answer of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227917/getting-html-array-length-with-javascript

Comment: I see now, just trying to understand the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`frm.elements['myInputs_1[]']` has a different behavior for each of the cases.

for no elements entered, it will be undefined

for 1 element, it only contains that element, so it does not have a length

for two elements onwards it is an object of type `RadioNodeList`, which is inherited from `NodeList` and has a `length` attribute.

so the validate form method changes to:

```
function validateForm(){
    var frm = document.forms['simples'];
    ele = frm.elements['myInputs_1[]'];
    if(typeof ele === 'undefined'){
        alert('no element at all..');
        return false;
    }

    else if(ele.value == ""){
        if (ele.length < 4){
            alert("You must write at least 4 sentences ");
            return false;
        }
    }
    else{
        alert('contains one element');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and it works!